# cmsfn.inherit() seems to return wrong type

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

In Magnolia 4.5.3, I'm trying to inherit a parent page's stage if none is defined for this.
The Java class `TemplatingFunctions` (exposed as `cmsfn` in freemarker) provides a method `inherit(Node content)`, so I'm trying the following:

```
[#if component??]
    [@cms.component content=component /]
[#else]
    [#assign inheritedContent = cmsfn.inherit(cmsfn.content(state.mainContent.@handle)) /]
    [@cms.component content=inheritedContent /]
[/#if]
```

But then I get an error:

```
The 'content' parameter must be a ContentMapModel and is a StringModel.
```

(line 6 in my example)

Why does this error occur, i.e. how could I resolve such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own inherit method, searching manually for a parent node with a stage, but at the end, instead of returning a Node, I return `new ContentMap(node)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that `cmsfn.content(path)` returns a `javax.jcr.Node`, and thus the overloaded `cmsfn.inherit` method will also return a `Node`, but `@cms.component` expects a `info.magnolia.jcr.util.ContentMap`. So, maybe you should convert the `Node` to a `ContentMap` with `cmsfn.asContentMap(someNode)`. (I'm telling this without knowing anything about Magnolia, just be looking at its API javadoc, so maybe I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yeah, the type was one of the problems, but I had to use `new ContentMap(node)` to get it to work.